# Error while starting MobileFirst 7.1 CLI Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

I'm getting the following Error while starting MobileFirst 7.1 Cli Server with command `mfp start`

```
Cannot find the server configuration. Creating a new MobileFirst test server.
The development server is being created.
The development server has been successfully created with the following information:
Server Directory: /Users/vamsik/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20160401-2103/server/
URL: http://localhost:10080/
Initializing MobileFirst Console.
objc[57651]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Starting server worklight.
Server worklight started with process ID 57650.
The server is listening on port 10080.
Server Directory: /Users/vamsik/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20160401-2103/server/
URL: http://localhost:10080/
Error: Deploy process failed.
```

I uninstalled the MobileFirst 7.1 CLI and installed it again but getting the same error while starting the server. I didn't start any other MobileFirst Servers even the Eclipse's MobileFirst Server.

When I gave `mfp push` I'm getting the following error

```
Preparing for push...
Error: error code: 126
Error: The MobileFirst server that you have configured does not appear to be running. Start the server with 'mobilefirst start'.
Error: SERVERNOTRUNNING
Error: Push has failed
```

Comment: After re-installing, did you use the same project you previously created? if yes, did you in fact start it first using "mfp start"? Or did you create a new project? Also, what is your Java version?

Comment: Do you have something else running on that port? MobileFirst typically uses three ports, 10080 (http), 10443 (http), and 10777 (for remote debug). You can check to see what is on these ports by using `lsof -i :<port#>`

Comment: @IdanAdar I tried with the old one and newly created Project but getting the same error. My Java version: "1.7.0_67". When I gave `mfp status` I getting message as Server is listening on port 10080

Answer (score 0):

Options to try:

1. Make sure that you also do not have MobileFirst Studio for Eclipse open and running
2. Rub "mfp stop", then "rm -rf .ibm" followed by creating a new project, navigating into it and then "mfp start"
3. Restart your workstation